# ajax request in CakePHP 2.7 but failed to return data

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am trying to perform ajax request when a link is click passing id value. And try to alert the data if successful. Please tell me what is wrong. I want to display the data in view.ctp then load it in the index.ctp after ajax request

```
$('a.view-btn').on('click', function(e){
        var view = $(this);
        var id = view.data('id');
        var href = view.attr('href');

        $.ajax({
            url: href,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {product_id: id},
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                $('div#view-contact').load(href + ' .view-contact');
            }
        });
        console.log(id);
    });
```

this is my edit method in controller

```
public function view($id) {         
        if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
            $this->autoRender = false;
            $this->set('contact', $this->request->data('product_id'));
            echo "AJAX SUCCESS";
        } else {
            $this->set('contact', $this->Contact->findById($id));
        }
    }
```

Comment: in chrome and mozilla i can alert "AJAX SUCCESS" but it will redirect to /contacts/view page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to add `dataType: 'json'` in `ajax`

```
$('a.view-btn').on('click', function(e){
            var view = $(this);
            var id = view.data('id');
            var href = view.attr('href');

        $.ajax({
            url: href,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {product_id: id},
            success: function(data) {
                $('div#view-contact').load(href + ' .view-contact');
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

and in my view method method I `echo json_encode($contact)`. And it works.

```
public function view($id) {         
        if ($this->request->is('POST')) {
            $this->autoRender = false;
            $contact = $this->request->data('product_id');
            $this->set('contact', $contact);
            echo json_encode($contact);
        } else {
            $this->set('contact', $this->Contact->findById($id));
        }
    }
```

but there are part in the code i dont understand. when I try to `echo "ajax success";` it means my ajax request is successful? then why can't I load the content of my view when i try to load it using jquery `$().load(href + ' .view-contact')`?

Answer (score 0):

```
use e.preventDefault().It will stop your page to refresh
$('a.view-btn').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var view = $(this);
        var id = view.data('id');
        var href = view.attr('href');

        $.ajax({
            url: href,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {product_id: id},
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                $('div#view-contact').load(href + ' .view-contact');
            }
        });
        console.log(id);
    });
```

Comment: yes i tried but how can I display the data in view.ctp and display it index? i tried to $('div#view-contact').load(href + ' .view-contact'); to display it but it fails.

Comment: what is value in href?

Comment: /bootstrap_exercise/contacts/view/47 sir. i tried to echo $this->request->data('product_id') but it returns null sir

Comment: its looks that problem is in view action